# i already installed the right .net framework version but my .exe file didn't run

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i already installed the .net framework version 4.0.30319 on this computer but my .exe file didnt work, im using win7 X86

Comment: didn't work means?Please add Any error message or something helpful to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be a bit more precise when you say 'your exe file'. Did you create your own in visual studio?
If yes, then remove all atributes you used from the MICROSOFT POWER PACK. Those don't work outside the compiler without having them installed on your computer manually. also you can release your program, by changing your debug button into a release button. After doing this hit f7 and your program should work.

Comment: i made my system on a different computer and now i'm trying it out in this computer, i'm trying to run it without opening the project on vb.net but i don't know what could be the problem, its not working here.